# I want to stream data from XML file using C# .net

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

The requirement is to read data from an XML file and stream data read from that XML file to specified IP Address and port no. I am thinking to use socket programming here. Please suggest the best way to do this. Data size can be in MBs, and as the recieved data will be real time, transfer rate should be fast.

Looking forward to helpful suggestions,

Regards,
Akki

Comment: Very broad question. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I don't understand quite what you want to do.  XML has opening and closing tags, so if there is a root node, the file won't actually be complete (and valid) until all of the data has been sent.  If you are talking about discrete records of (roughly) known size with no root it's achievable.  More info please!

Comment: @svick how to use HTTP, socket works on transport layer protocols I guess. The way is to use HTTP but how to use thats the main problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [WCF in streaming mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx) and avoid socket programming.

Comment: I am not aware of WCF. I am new to programming. I know WCF is an alternative